# C++ : Reading a "non-txt" file

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this file u.user that has some data about users in the following format:

835|44|F|executive|11577 
836|44|M|artist|10018

This is a text file basically but with the .user extension. I have been trying to use ifstream and getline methods to read one line at a time and store them in some sort of data structure, but it doesn't seem to be working. Error I get:

> userbaseGM.cpp:15:18: error: variable âstd::ifstream myfileâ has initializer but incomplete type
>     ifstream myfile ("u.user");

My code is:

```
int main() {
    //template<typename T> 
    //map<T,T> userMap;
    string line; 
    ifstream myfile ("u.user");
    if (myfile.is_open()) { 
        while ( getline (myfile,line) ) { 
            cout << line << '\n'; 
        } 
        myfile.close(); 
    } else cout << "Unable to open file";
}
```

Any suggestions on what I should be doing instead?

Thank you,

Comment: Would you copy your code?

Comment: Add the code that relates to the issue. Extensions mean nothing except for telling the OS how to open a file.

Comment: It's very unlikely that the extension of the file is causing the problem

Comment: The code is most likely your issue, as those above have stated. You likely have an error in your initialization of your ifstream.

Comment: @MM. below is my code:

int main() {

 //template<typename T>
 //map<T,T> userMap;
  string line;
 ifstream myfile ("u.user");
 if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 





}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"incomplete type": Some header file you included provided a forward declaration of the class, but you never included the real definition.

Add

```
#include <fstream>
```

near the top of your file, and try again.